# python-pptx insert picture in PlaceholderPicture

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to insert a picture in a pptx Placeholder

```
for shape in presentation.slides[(len(presentation.slides) - 1)].placeholders:
    print(shape.name)
    print(shape.shape_type)
    print(shape.placeholder_format.type)
    
    if "Bild" in shape.name:
        shape.insert_picture(os.path.join(self.image_folder, "media_value.png"))
```

my output:

```
Bildplatzhalter 17
PLACEHOLDER (14)
PICTURE (18)
```

the error:

```
shape.insert_picture(os.path.join(self.image_folder, "media_value.png"))
AttributeError: 'PlaceholderPicture' object has no attribute 'insert_picture'
```

From the [Documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/placeholders/slide-placeholders/picture-placeholder.html), it should work like this.
what i'm doing wrong?

*python3.9*
*python-pptx0.6.21*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder you are inserting into needs to be a picture placeholder rather than a text one.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

# Create a new presentation object
presentation = Presentation()

# Specify the slide layout. Slide layouts 8 has a picture placeholder
slide_layout = presentation.slide_layouts[8]

# Add a slide with the specified layout to the presentation
slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

# Specify the placeholder. Placeholder 1 is the picture placeholder.
# Choosing another placeholder will return an error
placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]

# Specify the path to the image file
img_path = "Animal 1.jpg"

# Add the image to the placeholder
placeholder = placeholder.insert_picture(img_path)

# Save the presentation
presentation.save('image.pptx')
```

Comment: The alternative is to get the dimensions/positioning of the placeholder. Removing it and inserting your image in its place.

Comment: that's what my code does: I use a bare bones template presentation - with just title placeholders. And then add everything else - tables, video, images, etc - in code.